# Magento 2 : How to Setup Persistent Shopping cart

Tags: magento2, cart, persistent

How to enable persistent shopping cart in magento 2.1?

**I want to do clear cart item on user sign out from sites.** I have already setup from

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Persistent Shopping Cart

**`Enable Persistence set to Yes`**,

**`Clear Persistence on Sign Out set to Yes`**

But nothing affect in cart items.

How to do this using persistent shopping cart functionality in magento 2?

**Goal: Remove Cart item when customer become logout.**

Comment: Which is exactly your Magento version?

Comment: Magento version is 2.1

Answer (score 1):

Please make change in following setting. Go to following setting in admin:

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Persistent Shopping Cart

**`Persist Shopping Cart set to No`**
If still it'll not work. Make small module like following.

---

To remove Cart item when customer logout. You can make small module for this functionality. The code is verified and it is working in Magento 2.1.

**app/code/Rohit/UserCart/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Rohit_UserCart',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Rohit/UserCart/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Rohit_UserCart" setup_version="1.0.0" >
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Rohit/UserCart/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_logout">
        <observer name="clearCartOnLogout" instance="Rohit\UserCart\Observer\EmptyCartLogout" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Rohit/UserCart/Observer/EmptyCartLogout.php**

```
<?php

namespace Rohit\UserCart\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;

/**
 * Class EmptyCartLogout
 * @package Rohit_UserCart
 */
class EmptyCartLogout implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerCart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * EmptyCartLogout constructor.
     * @param CustomerCart $cart
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerCart $cart

    ){
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->cart->truncate()->save();
    }
}
```

After that run following command at your magento root

> php bin/magento module:enable Rohit_UserCart
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope this will helpful to you